# How to remove name from legend in Highmaps

Tags: highcharts

I was using this https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/doubleclickzoomto as my application example and would like to ask how to remove the legend names (1, 10, 100, 1k)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the labels in this way:

```
    colorAxis: {
        ...,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2b0ngcsk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.labels.enabled